# Adding jQuery to Drupal module

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

I decided to use the method of including the file in my info file. Here is what I wrote:

```
scripts[] = https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js
scripts[] = screenshot.js
scripts[] = html2canvas-master/dist/html2canvas.js
```

I mixed javascript and jquery in screenshot.js. The javascript part is working fine, but something as simple as $("#btn").html("testing") is not working. So has jQuery been added incorrectly here?

Comment: Better use the module jquery_update. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to add a javascript file to everypage on your site (when the module is enabled).

However, jQuery is already bundled with Drupal (in [no-conflict mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)). That's likely your issue. If you need to update to jQuery 2.x your likely want to use the [jQuery Update module](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update). You need this module as it provide a compatibility layer so Drupal's own JavaScript will still work once you update jQuery. Otherwise, you will run into some compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7 includes jQuery with a standard install. It may be a little older than the version you require.

**Finding out the version of jQuery Drupal is loading**

After turning off js aggregation (Configuration > Development > Performance from the administrative menu), load your page and use browser tools to inspect the code. You should see all the javascript loaded with the page in the `<head>`. If the version of jQuery doesn't include the functions you need, add the module [jQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update). Configuring this module will allow you to choose the version of jQuery you need.

**Using jQuery on your Drupal site**

When creating your custom javascript, you can either leverage Drupal js behaviors, which are detailed in the article ["Understanding JavaScript Behaviors in Drupal"](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/understanding-javascript-behaviors-in-drupal). Or you can use good old `$( document ).ready()`.

**How to choose between Behaviors and Document Ready**

You will want to use behaviors if your page:

1. Loads AJAX content after the `$(document).ready()` event fires - and jQuery needs to act on that new content. Behaviors will take a pass through that new content, but just the new content, so you don't have crazy multiplying event listeners.
2. You have custom javascript that is only applicable for a very small bit of your site and shouldn't get loaded on every page. Define your context using behaviors.
3. Needs jQuery to know about a value pulled from the database / calculated by the PHP. With behaviors, you can pass a value from the PHP (server-side) to the javascript (client-side).

But `$(document).ready()` still works fine. It is namespaced, and in order to use the familiar $('.my-target') syntax you need to wrap your custom jQuery in a wrapper like this:

```
(function ($) {
  // All your code here
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.my-paragraph).css('border','1px solid lime');
    console.log('jQuery reporting for duty!');
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Check out the [Drupal docs for more info](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722). Make sure your syntax is tight! Those semicolons may be optional in some contexts, but Drupal sure is a little uptight about it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to add `scripts[] = https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js` in your theme info file. Because jQuery has been bundled in Drupal installation with below versions.

   - Drupal 7.42 - jQuery 1.4.4
   - Drupal 8.1.2 (latest) - jQuery 2.1.4
2. If you want other version of jQuery, please install jquery_update module. This module has fixed a lot of conflicts due to the incompatibility with core JavaScript.
3. Drupal has removed the global `$` wrap for jQuery. You can see the history and arguments from [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/125030)
4. [Behaviors](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722) to wrap all your code is the preferred way to add your own JavaScript code rather then the `$(document).ready()`.

   ```js
   (function($) {
     Drupal.behaviors.yourThemeName = {
       attach: function(context, settings) {
         // enter code here

         // this is example
         $('body', context).addClass('test');
       },
     }
   });
   ```

Comment: I still can't upvote here, so thank you for your answer!